# How to access history globally in react

Tags: reactjs

In react I can use this.props.history in Route components or using withRouter. But I want to access this globally from others components.
Is there any way? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can pass it done to child component as a props, or set it to redux state, and if necessary, make it a common HOC or something.

Comment: Or use [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html). ("_Context is designed to share data that can be considered “global” for a tree of React components_")

Comment: Did any post solve your problem? Kindly inform me if you have further questions.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using at least React 16.8.0 when hooks were introduced, the [useHistory hook](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Hooks/usehistory) will give you access to the history instance. This is essentially the modern equivalent of the `withRouter` HOC you mention in your question. Is there a reason this does not fit your needs?

You mention accessing it "globally", which makes me think you're looking for something like assigning the history instance to `window`, which you could of course do, but the hook/hoc are the more canonical approaches to getting access to history from a component.

Comment: Is `useHistory` compatible with react-router as well?

Comment: Yep, `useHistory` is exported out of react-router and react-router-dom simply re-exports it.

Comment: useHistory hook is for function component. I am working with class component.

Comment: So what exactly are you looking for beyond what `withRouter` does? The ability to access `history` without having to manually do anything?

Answer (score 1):

As the comment said, you can use [react context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html), or [redux](https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started) to pass your history to all the child components.

And, here is one solution about how you can catch the `history` via local HOC.

`component={BK}` => `component={RouteWithHistory(BK)}`

```
ReactDOM.render(
<Provider store={store}>
  <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/books" component={BK} />                   // Before 
        <Route exact path="/books" component={RouteWithHistory(BK)} /> // After
        <Route path="/details/" component={DT} />
        <Redirect to="/" />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
    </ThemeProvider>
</Provider>
,document.getElementById('root')
);
```

And the main function

```
interface Props {
  history: {location: {pathname: string}};
}
const RouteWithHistory = (Component: React.FC) => (props: Props) => {
  const pathname = props.history.location.pathname;
  console.log(pathname);
  // You can use redux here.
  // Or use the react context as below.
  const ThemeContext = React.createContext('');
  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={pathname}>
      <Component />
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  )
}
```